# How to create generic mapping with AutoMapper and ConstructUsing

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have a map configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<IDictionary<int, MyType1>, List<MyType1>>().ConstructUsing(
        x0 => x0?.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
});
```

How can I change this to work with "all MyTypes"?

I want to convert from `IDictionary<int, T>` to `List<T>` for any T type.

I found a very ugly solution:

```
cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IDictionary<,>), typeof(List<>)).ConstructUsing(
    x0 =>
    {
        if (x0 == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var dict = (IEnumerable)x0;
        var type = x0.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[1];
        var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
        CastDictionaryEntry(dict).OrderBy(x => x.Key).ForEach(x => list.Add(x.Value));
        return list;
    }
);
```

and:

```
static IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> CastDictionaryEntry(IEnumerable dict)
{
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        yield return (DictionaryEntry)item;
    }
}
```

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `dict.Values`?

Comment: I want to sort the dict.Values by the key in the result list.
so if the Dictionalry contains: {1, "a"}, {3, "b"}, {2, "c"} the result should be {"a", "c", "b"}, not random.
2nd problem is that the IEnumerable has no Values property. How can I access the Values property of the IDictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Comment: I can't cast it to IDictionary (non generic), because my Dictionary object is not IDictionary (for example NHibernate's PersistentGenericMap)

Answer (score 0):

I think works, but then again I haven't tested against a broad set of inputs-

```
class ABC
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
        public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    }
    static List<T> ConfigureMap<T>(Dictionary<int, T> input) where T : class
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap(input.GetType(), typeof(List<T>))
        .ConstructUsing(Construct));

        return Mapper.Map<List<T>>(input);

    }

    private static object Construct(object arg1, ResolutionContext arg2)
    {
        if (arg1 != null)
        {
            var val = arg1 as IDictionary;
            var argument = val.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[1];
            if (val != null)
            {
                var type = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(argument));

                foreach (var key in val.Keys)
                {
                    ((IList)type).Add(val[key]);
                }

                return type;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

var so = new Dictionary<int, ABC> { { 1, new ABC { MyProperty = 10, MyProperty2 = 30 } } };
var dest = new List<ABC>();
var res = ConfigureMap<ABC>(so);
```

Comment: In this case the dictionary entires are not sorted, and this solution is not easier. Reflection and Activaror.Creatinstance is still needed. I think this solution is more complicated than my solution.

Comment: Another problem is that "val" will be always null, because my object is not IDictionary, it is only IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
The only base non generic interface what I can use is the IEnumerable